# How to get different ip address to each docker container?

Tags: docker, networking, ip, docker-container, docker-network

My English is not very good. I’m sorry for that. I will try to explain my problem as much as possible.

I have a dedicated server

example to my dedicated server ip setting:

```
IP: 31.x.x.90/94
SUB: 255.x.255.248
GW: 31.x.x.89

ALTERNATIVE IP: 31.x.x.91/94
ALTERNATIVE IP: 31.x.x.92/94
ALTERNATIVE IP: 31.x.x.93/94
ALTERNATIVE IP: 31.x.x.94/94
```

My problem : I want to give different public static ip for each container. How can I do that?

Note:
Each container give the same ip address (31.x.x.90)
but I want it to give different `(example : container1 = 31.x.x.91 , container2 = 31.x.x.92)`

I was route all ip addresses to my server.

I tried to use macvlan,bridge etc. but it doesn’t accept this subnet `(similar to 255.255.255.x)`

Is there a way to solve this problem?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you hosting on an internal network or is the server publicly accessible?

Comment: You usually don't want to do this; it adds significant complexity to your setup.  (Do you assign separate IP addresses to the host ssh, cron, and HTTP daemons?)  The built-in Docker networking setup works fine in most cases; you can pair it with a load balancer (HAProxy, Nginx, AWS ELBs, ...) or a service-discovery system (Consul, ...) if you want a layer of indirection before contacting the host.

Comment: @DavidMaze In the past, I was creating multiple vm on a server. Instead I want to achieve less resource consumption by using the docker container. But I want to get different ip addresses like vm. I will not host web application in Docker. So port forwarding doesn't solve my problem.